# SignalR, Clientside function not getting called

Tags: signalr, client-side

I'm facing a strange issue, I'm able to call the server function but in return when  I try to call the client function , it does does not call
Am I doing something wrong or missing out some code or configuration to be done

I'm using Visual studio 2010 and developing a web app

the Server code just a simple class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRDemo
{
    public class MyHub:Hub 
    {
        public void GetMessage(string msg)
        {

             Clients.All.getMsg1("Got :"+msg);

        }

    }
}`
```

in global asax I have

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

Client Side code I just click the btn , it calls the server function GetMessage as expected but in return it does not call getMsg1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var chat = $.connection.myHub;
    chat.getMsg1 = function (msg) {
        debugger;
        alert(msg);
    };
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        chat.server.getMessage("called");
    });

    $.connection.hub.start() 
});
```

I googled I found that we need to register the client function before starting the hub conn which I did, but still it does not work nor it raises any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you're not having your client side function executed is because your binding it wrong.

Change:

```
chat.getMsg1 = function (msg) {
    debugger;
    alert(msg);
};
```

to

```
chat.client.getMsg1 = function (msg) {
    debugger;
    alert(msg);
};
```

Also one other thing to note as a good practice is you should always bind your event handlers one the connection has fully started.  So you can write your client code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var chat = $.connection.myHub;

    chat.client.getMsg1 = function (msg) {
        debugger;
        alert(msg);
    };  

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            chat.server.getMessage("called");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate ,saved my day ! + I have one more query. Is there any restriction on no. of server function I can call because I hit the btn quite a few time of course little quick and client side function did not excecuted that no.of time(basically the ratio is 5/ 10 ) But one thing I noticed that using Google Chrome I have no issues but using IE8 I have the issue. Is it due to restriction on no of simultaneous ajax call in IE8. Should not IE8 queue up the ajax calls Can you help me with few gooood links preferbly for 1.1.2 ?  I googled a bit but not able to find descent links for SignalR 1.1.2

Comment: The best resources for SignalR are found at http://www.asp.net/signalr.  As for your question, if you happen to exceed the max of 6 ajax calls concurrently in flight for IE8 you will absolutely not get all of your messages sent to the server.  However, for every method triggered on the server you should have all responses reach the client eventually.